# merge is duplicating columns, cannot reproduce

Tags: r

I have inherited a large and complicated R script which applies many operations to several large datasets.

At some point, the script:

1. Takes a `data.table`, makes a second summary table with something like `sum_tbl = as.data.table(init_tbl)[., x = sum(x), by = c('y', 'z')]`
2. Edits the values of `sum_tbl$z` and puts them in `sum_tbl$z_new`
3. Renames the summarized columns with `names(sum_tbl)[names(sum_tbl) == 'x'] = 'x_sum'`

At the end the summaries are merged with a statement like:

```
final_tbl = merge(init_tbl, sum_tbl, by.x = c('y', 'z'), by.y = c('y', 'z_new'), all.x = TRUE)
```

In the original environment, this script runs without issue. But when I attempt to migrate it to a new environment, this merge results in `final_tbl` having two columns, both called `z`, and breaks downstream code.

I tried to reproduce the issue, but failed. Obviously, there is a `final_tbl$z` which is not part of the merge key (`init_tbl$z` is matched with `init_tbl$z_new`), therefore it gets duplicated. Normal `merge` behavior in this case is to append a suffix to it, ie. `init_tbl$z` and `final_tbl$z` should become `sum_tbl$z` and `sum_tbl$z.y` respectively. In this particular case, the suffix is not added and instead `z` is duplicated.

Where would I begin to look to troubleshoot this problem?

- Are there any known bugs or "features" of `merge` that could result in duplicate columns with ambiguous names?
- Are there any global R settings that could affect this behavior?
- The real table has hundreds of columns, so should I investigate the role of name collisions in this (something that could have conceivably eluded my attempt at MWE)?

Comment: Are there some rows duplicated in `init_tbl` ? Try `merge` with `unique(init_tbl)` .

Answer (score 0):

Are you comfortable trying to rewrite portions of the code, specifically the merge/join, with a different library?

If you use `dplyr` you could try something like:

```
df_y$z <- df_y$z_new
final_tbl <- semi_join(init_tbl, sum_tbl, by = c("y", "z"))
```

I would probably rename the dfs, or run in a separate script, so you can compare the two merged/joined dfs to see if you get the same results. I'm not very experienced with `data.table` so I'm not sure what could be causing this issue.